# save() method in laravel only saving the last record in a json

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a loop iterating over some json data from an API, and I'm trying to save each iteration to the DB. The save() method is only saving one record with the data from the last iteration. Here is the snippet:

$movie = new Movies;

```
foreach ($movies['details'] as $details) 
{

    $movie->title = $details['original_title'];
    $movie->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is that you also need to loop through the model so that a new instance of the model is created each time the loop iterates.

```
foreach ($movies['details'] as $details) 
{
    $movie = new Movie; 
    $movie->title = $details['original_title'];
    $movie->save();

}
```